# Get value from a variable from another viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, instance, viewmodel

In ViewModel A I have a string variable `_projectName`

ViewModel A:

```
private string _projectName;
private void ProjectName(string ProjectName)
{
    _projectName = ProjectName;
}
```

When later on when ViewModel B gets called I want to use the value of this instance and use it to set as datasource for a DB connection

ViewModel B

```
String dbConnectionString = @"Data Source =" + _projectName + "" + ".sqlite";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a property:

```
Public string ProjectName
{
   get;
   private set;
}
private void ProjectName(string projectName)
{
    this.ProjectName = projectName;
}
```

In this way you can set this property from same class, but you can access it any where.

Answer (score -1):

The best way dee do you that is saving the `project name` in a `static` `property`, possibly because this information will be used in various parts of the application, so you do not depend on an `instance` to get it.
You could have a `static class` called `GeneralInformation`, which put all general information of your `project`.
An example follows:

```
public static class GeneralInformation
{
     public static String ProjectName {get;set;}

     //others general property's
}
```

Instead of using an `instance` to set the value of the `project name`, do the following:

```
GeneralInformation.ProjectName = "nameyourprojectname";
```

And to use the stored value of the `project name` in the `ViewModel B`, do the following:

```
String dbConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source ={0}.sqlite", GeneralInformation.ProjectName);
```

Comment: Using static classes in that way is against the spirit of MVVM (one of it being to have loose coupling) and causes tight coupling, makes unit testing much harder. if you really want do something like that in MVVM, you better make it a normal class (service of a kind)  and register it as singleton with your dependency injection container. Then one still has loose coupling